# Unable to get information from Promise {}

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I am working on a discord bot in discord.js. I am getting the target user using: `let target = message.guild.members.fetch(id)` This returns either `Promise { <pending> }` if the user has not sent any messages after the bot was restarted or `Promise { GuildMember: {information} }` if the user had sent messages. I am looking to access the information on the user if it is not pending.

I have tried:
`let target = message.guild.members.fetch(id) .then(console.log(target)`

and some other things. I don't really understand `Promise`

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You need to find a tutorial on Promises then.  A quesiton asking to explain a concept in full detail is too broad, and technically, shows a lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a **function** to `then`. (Currently you are passing the return value of `console.log(target)` which is useless)

The first argument passed to the function will be the resolved value from the Promise.

```
function log_the_value(the_value) {
    console.log(the_value);
}

const targetPromise = message.guild.members.fetch(id) 
targetPromise.then(log_the_value);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!